# pip error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

I updated to python 3.12 on windows and trying to `pip install -r requirements.txt`, but it terminates with error when trying to build `numpy`, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'`

requirements.txt

```
altgraph==0.17.4
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2023.7.22
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
click==8.1.7
contourpy==1.1.0
cycler==0.11.0
Flask==2.3.3
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
fonttools==4.42.1
idna==3.4
iniconfig==2.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.5
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
matplotlib==3.7.2
numpy==1.25.2
packaging==23.1
Pillow==10.0.0
pluggy==1.3.0
ply==3.11
pycparser==2.21
pyinstaller==6.1.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2023.10
pyparsing==3.0.9
PySpice==1.5
pytest==7.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
PyYAML==6.0.1
requests==2.31.0
scipy==1.11.2
six==1.16.0
urllib3==2.0.4
Werkzeug==2.3.7
```

EDIT:added requirements file

Comment: please share you requirements.txt file

Comment: @Lowsec-code added

Comment: Try it with `pip3`, cause sometimes `pip` is the pip for python2

Comment: @ayitinya it's your numpy version upgrade it too version 1.26

Comment: i believe some library depends on numpy and has pinned the version to 1.25.x, but i'd change to 1.26.x and give feedback

Comment: @ayitinya numpay added python 3.12 support in version +1.26 so ithink it's your problam if you can't change numpy version create python vertual env with lower python version

Comment: installed successfully after changing numpy to 1.26.x @Lowsec-code
hope i won't have to revert because another library broke. Thanks a lot